# Nodejs upload base64 image to azure blob storage using .createBlockBlobFromLocalFile()

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload profile picture of a user sent from web app and mobile app via Base64 form.

On the `POST` request they need to send a `JSON` on the body that looks something like this.

```
{
    "name":"profile-pic-123.jpg",
    "file":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxQTEhIUEhIUFBUV…K9rk8hCAEkjFMUYiEAI+nHIpsQh0AkisDYRTOiCAbWVtgCtI6IlkHh7LDTQXLH0EIQBj//2Q==" // the base64 image
}
```

Now on the server side using `Node` and `Express`, I used this npm module called `azure-storage` which offers a nice way of uploading files to azure blob storage using web service.

But there's something that I cannot understand on this. Here's a part of the code from my controller. I successfully created all neccessary connections and keys and whatnot to create a working `blobService` :

```
controllers.upload = function(req, res, next){

    // ...
    // generated some sastoken up here
    // etc.
    // ...

    var uploadOptions = {
        container: 'mycontainer',
        blob: req.body.name, // im not sure about this
        path: req.body.file // im not sure about this either
    }

    sharedBlobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(uploadOptions.container, uploadOptions.blob, uploadOptions.path, function(error, result, response) {
        if (error) {
            res.send(error);
        }
        console.log("result", result);
        console.log("response", response);
    });
}
```

Im getting this error:

```
{
    "errno": 34,
    "code": "ENOENT",
    "path": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAIAAAB..."
}
```

Answer (score 5):

if you use javascript sdk v12 You can use this sample code. It's just that simple. I have this implemented in a function and it works great when all I need it to trigger an HTTP event.

index.js

```
 const file = await require('./file')();
    uploadOptions = {
        container: 'mycontainer',
        blob: req.body.name, 
        text: req.body.file 
    }

      const fileUploader = await file(uploadOptions.text, uploadOptions.blob, 

uploadOptions.container);
```

You can use a separate module for your logic and call this from the index.js above

file.js

```
    const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
    const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);
const Promise = require('bluebird');

    module.exports = Promise.method(async function() {

        return async function (data, fileName, container) {
            const containerClient = await blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(container);
            const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(fileName);
            const matches = data.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/);
            const buffer = new Buffer(matches[2], 'base64');

            return await blockBlobClient.upload(buffer, buffer.byteLength );
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you should not use `createBlockBlobFromLocalFile`. Instead, you should use `createBlockBlobFromText`, because you are not uploading a local file, but content in the request body.

Here is the code:

```
var uploadOptions = {
    container: 'mycontainer',
    blob: req.body.name, 
    text: req.body.file 
}

sharedBlobService.createBlockBlobFromText(uploadOptions.container, 
                                           uploadOptions.blob, 
                                           uploadOptions.text, 
                      {
                         contentType: 'image/jpeg',
                         contentEncoding: 'base64'
                      }, 
                      function(error, result, response) {
                           if (error) {
                               res.send(error);
                           }
                           console.log("result", result);
                           console.log("response", response);
                      });
```

The `blob` is just the file name, which is "profile-pic-123.jpg" this case, and `path` is the local path to your file. Since you are not storing the file locally in the server side, `path` is meaningless in the case.

If you need more information about Storage, see [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage/), and [this](http://willi.am/blog/2014/07/02/azure-blob-storage-and-node-creating-blobs/)

Comment: Will this upload the actual image to the azure blob storage? Let's say if I go to `https://myblob.blob.azure.something.net/mycontainer/theimageiuploaded.jpg` will I get the visual of the image or just the text form?

Comment: in this case, it should be `https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/profile-pic-123.jpg`. If your container is public, you can get the image directory from this URL. If it's private, you need authorization in order to get the image.

Comment: I used this code now im getting this error 

{
  "code": "ResourceNotFound",
  "statusCode": 404,
  "requestId": "bc789061-0001-0022-37f3-80a7c8000000"
}

Comment: Make sure that you have already created a container in your Storage account. Use `sharedBlobService.createContainerIfNotExists('mycontainer', function(error, result, response){if(!error){}});` to create a container

Comment: Im sure that the container exist. :/

Comment: I got nothing to say. I have tested my code and it works for me. please copy `sharedBlobService.createContainerIfNotExists('mycontainer', function(error, result, response){if(!error){}});` into your code before `sharedBlobService.createBlockBlobFromText`, and test it again.

Comment: I tested createContainerIfNotExists() already and it is working. By the way the image im uploading now is in this format `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxQTEhIUEhIUFBUV…K9rk8hCAEkjFMUYiEAI+nHIpsQh0AkisDYRTOiCAbWVtgCtI6IlkHh7LDTQXLH0EIQBj//2Q==`

Bu i still got the error saying `ResourceNotFound`

Comment: For that part, you need to set the header Content-Type to be 'image/jpeg' and Content-Encoding to be 'base64'. Please read the 2 links I provided in the answer, and go through the tutorial. After that, you will have some basic idea about Azure Storage

Comment: There is a `createWriteStreamToBlockBlob` which should be useful in your case.

Comment: What does this `createWriteStreamToBlockBlob` do? Ill try it. Thanks!

Comment: After using `createWriteStreamToBlockBlob` the request just timed out without any callback not even error or the response argument.

Comment: Oh man, please read the links, `createWriteStreamToBlockBlob` is using pipe stream. not like `createBlockBlobFromLocalFile` or `createBlockBlobFromText`

Comment: Same error. Resource not found. Oh god this is getting ridiculous xD

Comment: By the way here's the full code, I posted another question regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36080854/nodejs-uploading-base64-image-to-azure-blob-storage-results-to-resourcenotfound?noredirect=1#comment59806807_36080854

Comment: I have read your new question. @MineTanrinianDemir-MSFT  is giving the right answer.

Comment: Above slice of code works well for me, but everytime I upload image to azure blob the content-type I get is application/octet-stream. How to set the content -type as image/png or image/jpg??