# Nodejs uploading base64 image to azure blob storage results to "ResourceNotFound" error

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

Here is the post request `JSON` :

```
{
    "name":"images.jpg",
    "file":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxQTEhIUEhIUFBUV…K9rk8hCAEkjFMUYiEAI+nHIpsQh0AkisDYRTOiCAbWVtgCtI6IlkHh7LDTQXLH0EIQBj//2Q=="
}
```

And here's my node controller under the request `/upload` route, I am using `createBlockBlobFromText()` from [azure-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage).

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService('myblob.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer', THE_KEY);

controllers.upload = function (req, res, next){

    var startDate = new Date();
    var expiryDate = new Date(startDate);

    var sharedAccessPolicy = {
        AccessPolicy: {
            Permissions: azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
            Start: startDate,
            Expiry: expiryDate
        }
    };

    var sharedAccessSignatureToken = blobSvc.generateSharedAccessSignature('resources', req.body.file, sharedAccessPolicy);
    var sharedBlobService = azure.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobSvc.host.primaryHost + '/' + 'mycontainer' + '?' + sharedAccessSignatureToken);

    sharedBlobService.createBlockBlobFromText('mycontainer', req.body.name, req.body.file, function(error, result, response) {
        if (error) {
            res.send(error);
            return;
        }
        res.send(result);
    });

}
```

However I am getting this error.

```
{
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "statusCode": 404,
    "requestId": "bffa6099-0001-000b-53f9-80d18a000000"
}
```

Comment: One obvious question: does the container exist in your storage account?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes it does Im more than 100% sure.

Comment: @GauravMantri am I passing the right format of image as `"data:image/jpeg..."` to `createBlockBlobFromText()` function?

Comment: (Not in front of a computer) can you try by removing "/my container" when you're creating blobSvc variable?

Comment: @GauravMantri still he same. `"code":"ResourceNotFound"`

Answer (score 4):

Couple of changes needed:

- expiration date should be greater than start date.
- shared access signature should use same container name.
- shared access signature should be passed in file name, not file content.

After these changes, the code would be similar to this:

```
var sharedAccessSignatureToken = blobSvc.generateSharedAccessSignature('mycontainer', req.body.name, sharedAccessPolicy);
var sharedBlobService = azure.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobSvc.host, sharedAccessSignatureToken);

sharedBlobService.createBlockBlobFromText('mycontainer', req.body.name, req.body.file, function(error, result, response) {
        if (error) {
            res.send(error);
            return;
        }
        res.send(result);
    });
```

Comment: Mine's answer is completely right, but you actually don't need to be using start date at all. If it's not set, the service will just check that the date is before the expiry which looks like what you want. If you use start date it can also cause issues where the SAS doesn't work immediately if there's clock skew between your computer and the storage server.