# Azure Storage Blobs - Upload base64 as Text

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an API server method that accept getting files as BASE64. Getting request like this:

```
{
    file: "-BASE 64 HERE-"
}
```

I want that my server will get this `file` and store it on Azure Storage. So, I running this code:

```
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("file.zip");
var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(Model.File);
await blob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

**It's working, but inefficient.**

Why? Because the same bytes have *two* instances in my main memory: as byte array + as stream.

I wounder if it possible to upload the BASE64 as text, and letting the server understand that this is BASE64 - which will be treated like a file.

In that way I will upload the text directly without convert it to stream.

Is this possible?

May be linked to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079353/nodejs-upload-base64-image-to-azure-blob-storage-using-createblockblobfromlocal)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use [UploadFromStreamAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfromstreamasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlockBlob_UploadFromStreamAsync_System_IO_Stream_)?

Comment: Because I need to convert the base64 to stream and then upload it. It will be faster to upload it as text. If it small file, it will be OK. If it large file, it will consume resources.